# Solubility and pressure

Tags: physical-chemistry

Does really pressure don't influence solubility of a solute in a solution? For example,at saturated water with NaCl at 1Atm has the same kg solute / kg of water,in saturated state with NaCl at 1000Atm?

Thank you.

P.S.: I red pressure doesn't influence solubility of a solute in a solvent ,for liquids,but in this limit cases like 10000m of deep in oceans?

Answer (score 0):

Found. Solubility varies with the pressure;more pressure,more solute melts...